# how can we use document.querySelectorAll to get all the tags in a html page

Tags: javascript, dom

Someone suggested me to use `document.querySelectorAll("#tagContainingWrittenEls > *")` to get a reference to all the written tags. Then you can loop over 'em all, and do `.tagName` and `.attributes` on each element in the list to get the info.

But This can only be done if there is a class named #tagContainingWrittenEls. I thought this is some method

Comment: `document.querySelectorAll('body > *');` will give you all the elements in the page. As you stated, your solution will only work if that id or class is present. Due to how the web works, the body tag will always be available.

Answer (score 7):

The `querySelectorAll` function takes a [selector string](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#selectors) returns a `NodeList` which can be iterated through like an array.

```
// get a NodeList of all child elements of the element with the given id
var list = document.querySelectorAll("#tagContainingWrittenEls > *");

for(var i = 0; i < list.length; ++i) {
    // print the tag name of the node (DIV, SPAN, etc.)
    var curr_node = list[i];
    console.log(curr_node.tagName);

    // show all the attributes of the node (id, class, etc.)
    for(var j = 0; j < curr_node.attributes.length; ++j) {
        var curr_attr = curr_node.attributes[j];
        console.log(curr_attr.name, curr_attr.value);
    }
}
```

The breakdown of the selector string is as follows:

- The `#nodeid` syntax refers to a node with the given id.  Here, the
  hypothetical id of `tagContainingWrittenEls` is used -- your id will probably
  be different (and shorter).
- The `>` syntax means "children of that node".
- The `*` is a simple "all" selector.

Taken all together, the selector string says "*select all children of the node with the id of "tagContainingWrittenEls*".

See http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#selectors for a list of CSS3 selectors; they are quite important (and handy) to advanced Web development.

Comment: i didn't understand what the selector string in this example is indicating and also does the output contains all the tags in the html or only the tags created by document.write or document.body.innerHTML

Comment: The `#nodeid` syntax refers to a node with the given id (here, the hypothetical id of `tagContainingWrittenEls`), and the `>` syntax means "children of that node".  The `*` is a simple "all" selector.

Taken all together, the selector says "get all children of the node with the id of "tagContainingWrittenEls".

Comment: ok now i don't have any like tagContainingWrittenEls so does that mean it doesn't work for me because i am tracking the tags with class id but i am trying to track the tags created dynamically

Comment: The id I used is just an example; you can make it the id of an element that's actually on your page.  Also, selectors can gather elements from all over the page: if you want to get a NodeList with *all* the elements that have the `tagbox` class, for example, just use the period operator: `querySelectorAll(".tagbox")`.  If you need nodes that have both `tagbox` and `darkred`: `querySelectorAll(".tagbox.darkred")`.

Comment: If you can't get the selector quite right after you've read the spec and tried a few things, it might be appropriate to post a new question like, "I have HTML structured like this... what is the correct selector string to get the particular elements I want?"

Answer (score 2):

According to MDN, [.querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Document.querySelectorAll)

> Returns a list of the elements within the document (using depth-first pre-order traversal of the document's nodes) that match the specified group of selectors. The object returned is a NodeList.

---

[.querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Document.querySelectorAll) returns a list of elements that match the selector provided.

it's like how you style in CSS: you create a selector, put in the properties you want to apply to these target elements then these elements get styled.

say in CSS, you want to style all `<a>` in `<li>` that are under `<ul>` with an `id` of `list` with the color `red`. You will have this:

```
ul#list li a{
    color:red;
}
```

in effect, all `<a>` in an `<li>` under a `<ul>` with an `id` of `list` turns to red.

now take that same selector to get via JavaScript these same `<a>` elements

```
var anchors = document.querySelectorAll('ul#list li a');
```

now `anchors` will contain a `NodeList` (an array-like structure) that contains a reference to all `<a>` in an `<li>` under a `<ul>` with an `id` of `list`. Since a `NodeList` is like and `Array`, you can loop through it, and each item is an `<a>` in an `<li>` under a `<ul>` with an `id` of `list`.

---

and of course, it only gets the elements that are in the DOM at the time the code is executed.